# Reports for permissions to Informix user

Tags: informix

I want to generate a report file based on the permissions granted to an Informix user for three different tables like follows:

```
        USER Report

USER    tbl1    tbl2    tbl3

A       1       0       0
B       1       0       0
C       0       1       1
D       0       1       1
```

In the above example 1 denotes user 'A' and 'B' has 'SELECT' permission on the 'tbl1' table and user 'C' and 'D' has 'SELECT' permission on the 'tbl2' and 'tbl3' tables.

I went through internet and got **dbschema** command. But its output is different then required.

Please guide me to generate this report.

Comment: You have woefully underspecified your problem.  You have not specified what the 0 and 1 values mean — there are many permissions, including SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER, INDEX.  There are column-level privileges as an option too; what should be the result if the user can view all but 3 columns but update on 2 columns?  Next up: you need to consider PUBLIC permissions too — if the PUBLIC can do something, so can A (and B and C and D).  And there are options for different users to grant different permissions on the same table to a given user.  The permissions accumulate.

Comment: So, you need to specify a lot more about what this report is supposed to convey.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I have edited my question.

Comment: Just for tables Informix has at  least 8 types of privileges. You need to specify which set of privileges you consider to correspond to "permission on table".

Comment: I see the edit.  Sadly, it fails to address my question entirely.  Which permission do you mean?  I suspect you are thinking of SELECT permission — the ability to retrieve data from the table — but you've not stated that.  You also haven't addressed my question about PUBLIC permissions.  There are column-level privileges too; most people don't use them, so that can probably be ignored.  There are also group or role privileges; do those need to be analyzed?  Another minority concern is 'WITH GRANT OPTION'; do you need to know about that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I have added privileges in my question.

Comment: Hmmm; I'm confused.  How am I to know that 1 means different things in different columns?  How will you specify what 1 means in each different column?  What should be done if there are 200 tables in the database?   Do you specify which tables you want to know about?  What if there are  200 users, or do you specify which users you're interested in?  What should happen if the table names are 128 characters long, or the user names are 32 characters long? These are the sorts of issues programmers, including DBAs, have to think about and deal with. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ You may legitimately decide to ignore some issues.  You should be aware that you are doing so.  You've not mentioned column level privileges.  There could be ways of saying "these N users have the same privileges on the tables, and those privileges are …"; that's fiddly to do in pure SQL, but possibly doable in a reporting tool.  Oh, and we've not discussed what tools are in use — DB-Access, Informix-SQL, Informix-4GL, ESQL/C, ODBC, JDBC, something else?  Specifying programs requires lots of details.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Number of tables are fixed which is only 3 and their name is not huge. I will specify the table names and want to know which user has 'SELECT' privilege on these tables. The length of the user name is considered while creating it. My report will come into the picture when the user is created and privileges were assigned in these three tables. I am concentrating on 'SELECT' privilege right now. I don't need field level privileges.